# error: non-numeric argument to binary operator, but class is numeric

Tags: r, error-handling

I am trying to sum up two columns and obtaining the error: non-numeric argument to binary operator. However both columns are numeric. So I do not understand why I get this error message. Thanks for your help?

```
data_all<-data_all %>% mutate(total='5min'+'10min')
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.
> class(data_all$`5min`)
[1] "numeric"
> class(data_all$`10min`)
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: You are using quotes around the column names in mutate, this causes you to try to add up characters.

Comment: Hi Sven, thanks for the comment. If I remove the quotes, then it gives me a different error message data_all<-data_all %>% mutate(total=5min+10min)
Error: unexpected symbol in "data_all<-data_all %>% mutate(total=5min"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks to refer to columns that have a number as their first character in their name. I've reproduced it as follows:

```
library(data.table)

data_all <- data.table("5min" = c(1:10), "10min" = c(11:20))
data_all$`5min` <- as.numeric(data_all$`5min`)
data_all$`10min` <- as.numeric(data_all$`10min`)

data_all<-data_all %>% mutate(total=`5min` +`10min`)
```